# Transpose function in Notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++, transpose

I have a text file as:

```
0xC1,0x80,
0x63,0x00,
0x3F,0x80,
0x01,0xA0,
```

I want output as:

```
Line1: 0xC1,0x63,0x3F,0x01,
Line2: 0x80,0x00,0x80,0xA0,
```

How to do this using replace function in Notepad++?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible with N++. You'd better use a script to do such tranformation.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the below shortcuts to do the transpose in Notepad ++

```
 Step 1: Ctrl + A: selects all.
 Step 2: Ctrl + J: Transpose the Row you selected
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this tip as earlier tip to use the replace with regex \r\n did not work. Ctrl+J work for my npp v7.8.6 (64 bit on win10 enterprise) and in another npp v7.6.4 (win server 2019 deployed by IT to use in citrix)

Comment: Note that `Ctrl + J` is the `Edit > Line Operations > Join Lines` option. The `Find and Replace` answer from @Noel is more general and can be preferred in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use the box select feature to select the second column text.

   - Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arraw keys</kbd> to select the second column.
2. Copy the selected text to a new file.
3. Use Find/Replace to remove all the newline characters.

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open find/replace dialog box.
   - Select either ***Extended*** or ***Regular Expression*** Serach mode.
   - Type ***\r\n*** in ***Find What*** box.
   - Keep the ***Replace with*** box blank.
   - Click on ***Replace All in ALL Open Documents***.
   - Now, the text is brought in single line.
4. Copy the text from second file and paste it to second line of first file.

Cheers...

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in function in Notepad++ for transposing a matrix and you can't do it using Replace (as M42 pointed out). Also, I'm not aware of any related plugin. So you will either need a different editor or do it with a script. The simplest solution I guess using a Spreadsheet, eg Excel or OpenOffice, both of them allow you to easily transpose a table.

But, there's still a good alternative without leaving Notepad++. Is to use the `Python Script` plugin.

### Setup Python Script plugin

1. Install `Python Script` plugin, from `Plugin Manager` or from the [official website](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/).
2. When installed, go to `Plugins > Python Script > New Script`. Choose a filename for your new script (eg `transpose.py`) and copy the first code block that follows and copy the second one to another script, called for example `transpose_uneven.py`.
3. Open your data file and then run `Plugins > Python Script > Scripts > transpose.py`. This will open a new tab with your data transposed.

#### transpose.py

```py
delimiter=","
newline="\n"
content=editor.getText()
matrix=[line.split(delimiter) for line in content.rstrip(newline).split(newline)]
transposed=list(map(list, zip(*matrix)))
notepad.new()
for line in transposed:
    editor.addText(delimiter.join(line) + newline)
if len(transposed)!=len(matrix[0]):
    console.clear()
    console.show()
    console.write("Warning: some rows are of uneven length. You might consider using the transpose_uneven script instead.")
```

#### transpose_uneven.py

```py
import itertools    
delimiter=","
newline="\n"    
content=editor.getText()
matrix=[line.split(delimiter) for line in content.rstrip(newline).split(newline)]
transposed=list(map(list, itertools.izip_longest(*matrix, fillvalue="")))
notepad.new()
for line in transposed:
    editor.addText(delimiter.join(line) + newline)
```

### Examples

The `transpose.py` script will transpose the following example:

```
0xC1,0x80,
0x63,0x00,
0x3F,0x80,
0x01,0xA0,
```

To:

```
0xC1,0x63,0x3F,0x01
0x80,0x00,0x80,0xA0
,,,
```

If some of your rows are uneven:

```
0xC1,0x80,
0x63,0x00,
0x3F,0x80,
0x01,0xA0,
0x02
```

The uneven columns will be discarded accordingly:

```
0xC1,0x63,0x3F,0x01,0x02
```

If this is not desired, use `transposed_uneven.py` and it will return:

```
0xC1,0x63,0x3F,0x01,0x02
0x80,0x00,0x80,0xA0,
,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have such a fixed format and need such a fixed output i normally try it with an instant macro.

So my cursor is in the top left corner of the file ready to manipulate and i press the record button (or within the menu bar *Macro - Start recording*).

In you specific case now press:

- <kbd>End</kbd>
- <kbd>Del</kbd>
- <kbd>Pos1</kbd>
- <kbd>↓</kbd>

End hit the stop button (or within the menu bar *Macro - Stop recording*).

Now for a first test hit the playback button (or within the menu bar *Macro - Playback*) and test if it works. If yes click on *Macro - Run a macro multiple times* and select *Run until the end of file*.